# How to assign weights in a groupby within subgroups in conjunction with conditional statements in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, data-manipulation

[image]Hi,

I have this dataset that has 7 columns (see image). First, I want to group by the Name column, afterwards I want to assign weights as follows:

1. Compute 10% of 1/n (if Provider for a Name is more than 1) for all n number of IDs in a Name. n = count of unique ID for one name. So for Sammy for example, n = 2.
2. Add 5% of 1/n if the column Accel_5 is 1, add an extra 10% of 1/n if the Accel_10 is 1 and add an extra 15% of 1/n if the Accel_15 is 1.
3. Add 10% for each additional tech

Altogether, groupby Name(Sammy, Josh, Sarah), then compute; 10% of 1/n(if provider is greater than 1) + 5% of 1/n(if Accel_5 is equal to 1) + 10% of 1/n (if Accel_10 is equal to 1) + 15% of 1/n (if Accel_15 is equal to 1) + 10% of 1/n (for each additional tech).

I have been able to groupby name only and I have gotten the unique number of IDs by name but I am stuck. See sample code below:

```
sample = pd.read_csv("Records.csv")
test = sample.groupby("Name")
test["ID"].nunique()
```

Link to data: [Link to image depicted above](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ncOiVPXFMqKbtSbfiFe4dcOf9Vt6t1Nr/view?usp=sharing)

I appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to create a custom function, and then use `.apply()` as:

```
def assign_weights(x):
    n = len(x['ID'].unique())
    x["Weight"] = 0

    # 1.
    n_providers = len(x['Provider'].unique())
    if n_providers > 1:
        x["Weight"] += 0.1 * 1/n

    # 2. 
    if 1 in x['Accel_5']:
        x["Weight"] += 0.05 * 1/n
    if 1 in x['Accel_10']:
        x["Weight"] += 0.1 * 1/n
    if 1 in x['Accel_15']:
        x["Weight"] += 0.15 * 1/n

    # 3.
    n_tech = len(x['Tech'].unique())
    x["Weight"] += 0.1 * n_tech

    return x


sample.groupby("Name").apply(lambda x: assign_weights(x))
```

This creates a new column `Weight`, based on the conditions 1, 2 and 3 you supplied. Because you did not specify the input data in an appropriate manner (not using an image), I have not tested the code, but I believe it should work as intended.

Comment: The code ran but not as intended. The weight for each name is intended to be the same. Here is a link to the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GD1swUFqvinTwyc7Mef-hbVR1TEcljMP/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please clarify how this is possible with your current description,  "add an extra 10% of 1/n if the `Accel_10` is 1", but for Sammy, `Accel_10` is both 0 and 1.

Comment: I have updated the link so please use this instead: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ncOiVPXFMqKbtSbfiFe4dcOf9Vt6t1Nr/view?usp=sharing. The computation is by name and not by ID, so for Sammy, n = 2 since unique ID is 1 and 2. Thus, regardless of what ID 1 says for Accel_10, the computation for Sammy is 10% of 1/2 (provider >1) + 5% of 1/2 (Accel_5==1) + 10% of 1/2 (Accel_10==1) and so on. Actual data is way more complicated than this so pls forgive me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I understand that it is based on name and not ID, but you say that for Sammy "...+ 10% of 1/2 Accel_10...", but my point is that Sammy have four rows, where Accel_10 is `1` for two rows and `0` for the other two. You want to condition `weight`, which should be a scalar value for each name, based on the value of Accel_10, therefore I am confused. Is your condition that Accel_5 is `1` at any row for Sammy? If you help me understand the condition, I can rewrite my answer so that it work as you intend.

Comment: I see what you mean. Yes, Accel_5 is 1 at any row for Sammy. in fact, it is impossible to have Accel_10 without Accel_5. Is it possible to compute; say wherever there is Accel_5 or Accel_10 == 1 for a name. Do the following weight calculation. The only relevance for ID is to compute n. I hope this clarifies things a bit.

Comment: It is still a bit unclear. If the weight calculation only should be done when Accel_5 or Accel_10 is equal to `1`, we can start off by removing all those rows as, `sample = sample[(sample["Accel_5"] != 1) || (sample["Accel_10"] != 1)]`? And then perform the calculation, since we should never perform it when any of the Accel_X is 0?

Comment: I agree with your point that we can remove the rows where Accel_5/10... != 1. But won't you miss out the count for n for each name? This discussion may be moved to a chat. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The question boils down to: if you want **one** scalar weight for every name, what condition, for every name, do you want on 'Accel_X'? Either it can be that Accel_X has to be `1` for _any_ row, or it can be some _other_ condition, but so far you have not provided a clear answer. If you provide a clear answer, the problem is possible to solve.

Comment: Ok, let's use Accel_5 has to be 1 for the condition. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223164/discussion-between-marcus-and-shegs01).